# Any rules of thumb to fix this non-functioning board I just made?

Tags: pcb, debugging

I just reflowed this PCB. It is a 20 x 16 mm PCB with a Nordic nRF52832 Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) SoC IC. I powered it on and the regulator, mounted on the back, got very hot.

I measured the Vcc and GND outputs of the 3 V regulator and read 50 ohms. That is wrong. I checked all my capacitors, since I suspected it was something connecting Vcc and GND, and they seem fine.

I found a solder bridge on the nRF chip and fixed it. I would expect to see a short if there were problems, but not 50 ohms. I have no resistors between Vcc and GND that could cause this. Where would 50 ohms come from? I accidentally connected power to the regulator backwards at first, maybe something is wrecked.

[image]

I took the suggestions here and then built another one. This one I could program and blink the LED. I was helped by your comments. Here is a photo of it working. The photo caught when the LED was on.

[image]

Comment: Depending on what multimeter you use and polarity it is possible that a diode junction gives a 50 ohm reading on the meter.

Comment: Yes. Maybe something is wrecked. Can you assemble another one? Or do you only have the one?

Comment: If you wanted us to do a visual inspection, get a picture which actually shows something from the board. Right now we have a nice antenna on a wooden table.

Comment: Yep, your photo looks like the whole PCB is a single solder bridge.

Comment: 555s can take a lot of abuse and continue working,  but the same is not true of many  more complex chips

Comment: Can't you see that the photo is horribly out of focus? Even pushing the board a few inches away into where the lovely table is in focus would be better!

Comment: Did you give the PCB a close inspection before putting parts on it? Maybe a trace didn't get etched quite right and is shorted to another one. You could use a magnifying glass for immediately obvious problems and a continuity tester to make sure.

Comment: I had a hard time getting a good photo with my cell phone, sorry about the bluriness. I am going to take the advice on these threads and pop the regulator off and check the board again. I will also check a bare PCB for defects, and then I will also build another one as suggested.

Comment: Here is a better photo.

Comment: -1 for a little board in the middle of a big picture.  This really should have been obvious. You couldn't even be bothered to crop the large picture to cut out the irrelevant parts!

Comment: Looks like I goofed in my question. I wasn't thinking I was implying people should debug the board visually by the photo, I was showing what I was working on and then asking for basic advice. So sorry if I gave that impression. I did what was suggested, I built another one, and it worked. I will put up a photo of that, again just to show it's working.

Comment: Again, really sorry Olin. You are the engineer's engineer and an inspiration since I have been on stackexchange. Not the guy I want to annoy.

Comment: Was there any time ESD/EOS protection was ignored?

Comment: Congrats on getting it working, but you seem to have ignored the issues pointed out with your previous photo - yet again, you have a large image with only a small fraction of relevant content.  Even if your picture isn't great, you should still crop it to only the relevant part.  And then yet again, a picture of your board doesn't really demonstrate anything that is relevant to its (non)functionality.  Something like a schematic with a "this gets hot" and "I measure xx here" might actually have been useful.  Though in the end the key lesson appears to be "if you zapped it, you must replace it"

Comment: I added a cropped picture. Seems I ended up frustrating everyone by including a photo that was difficult to see.

Comment: Yet you still also have an *uncropped* picture.

Comment: You mean the top one of the 2?

Comment: You've posted quite a small number of photos. @ChrisStratton means the one which is not cropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Board getting hot is a clear sign of potential permanent damage. Even if that solder bridge was the only issue, powering the IC while this bridge was present had a good chance of damaging it irreversibly (sometimes ICs survive such abuse, but this rarely happens when you count on it).

Having some resistance with a defective IC is to be expected. If there was a 0 Ohm short between VCC and GND, your board wouldn't get hot in the first place. Also, resistance value by itself is not very helpful: 50 Ohm could be 60mA @ 3V (hardly enough to get hot) or 20mA @ 1V (which could become 1A when you apply 3V).

Do a thorough visual inspection on the next board before you power it on.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging a PCB is quite a task. I would start from the supply and remove the regulator and substitute it with a lab supply instead. Then check if the voltage and current are what you expect.

If that's not the case, I consider it faster having a new board, finding and fixing a component destroyed is quite hard and can be expensive if you smoke other components on your way. Try giving your layout a review if everything connects where it should and if the spaces around the traces are wide enough.